# Most efficient way to search enumerable

Tags: c#, performance, linq, dynamics-crm, processing-efficiency

I am writing a small program that takes in a .csv file as input with about 45k rows. I am trying to compare the contents of this file with the contents of a table on a database (SQL Server through dynamics CRM using Xrm.Sdk if it makes a difference).

In my current program (which takes about 25 minutes to compare - the file and database are the exact same here both 45k rows with no differences), I have all existing records on the database in a `DataCollection<Entity>` which inherits `Collection<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`

In my code below I am filtering using the `Where` method and then doing a logic based the count of matches. The `Where` seems to be the bottleneck here. Is there a more efficient approach than this? I am by no means a LINQ expert.

```
foreach (var record in inputDataLines)
{
    var fields = record.Split(',');

    var fund = fields[0];
    var bps = Convert.ToDecimal(fields[1]);
    var withdrawalPct = Convert.ToDecimal(fields[2]);
    var percentile = Convert.ToInt32(fields[3]);
    var age = Convert.ToInt32(fields[4]);
    var bombOutTerm = Convert.ToDecimal(fields[5]);

    var matchingRows = existingRecords.Entities.Where(r => r["field_1"].ToString() == fund
                                      && Convert.ToDecimal(r["field_2"]) == bps
                                      && Convert.ToDecimal(r["field_3"]) == withdrawalPct
                                      && Convert.ToDecimal(r["field_4"]) == percentile
                                      && Convert.ToDecimal(r["field_5"]) == age);

    entitiesFound.AddRange(matchingRows);

    if (matchingRows.Count() == 0)
    {
        rowsToAdd.Add(record);
    }
    else if (matchingRows.Count() == 1)
    {
        if (Convert.ToDecimal(matchingRows.First()["field_6"]) != bombOutTerm)
        {
            rowsToUpdate.Add(record);
            entitiesToUpdate.Add(matchingRows.First());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        entitiesToDelete.AddRange(matchingRows);
        rowsToAdd.Add(record);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I can confirm that all `existingRecords` are in memory before this code is executed. There is no IO or DB access in the above loop.

Comment: Looks like you're doing 45k * 45k comparisons, that does mount up. Still, 25 minutes seems  too long. Can you confirm that existingRecords is in-memory, not needing any file (db) access?

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes I can confirm that all existingRecords are in memory before this code is executed. There is no IO or DB access in the above loop.

Comment: In that case @HenkHolterman my assumption in giving answer was wrong.

Comment: @IpsitGaur - yes, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Himbrombeere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46788696/284240) is right, you should execute the query first and put the result into a collection before you use `Any`, `Count`, `AddRange` or whatever method will execute the query again. In your code it's possible that the query is executed 5 times in every loop iteration.

<sup>Watch out for the term *deferred execution* in the documentation. If a method is implemented in that way, then it means that this method can be used to construct a LINQ query(so you can chain it with other methods and at the end you have a query). But only methods that don't use deferred execution like `Count`, `Any`, `ToList`(or a plain `foreach`) will actually execute it. If you dont want that the whole query is executed everytime and you have to access this query multiple times , it's better to store the result in a collection(.f.e with `ToList`).</sup>

However, you could use a different approach which should be much more efficient, a `Lookup<TKey, TValue>` which is similar to a dictionary and can be used with an anonymous type as key:

```
var lookup = existingRecords.Entities.ToLookup(r => new 
{
    fund = r["field_1"].ToString(),
    bps = Convert.ToDecimal(r["field_2"]),
    withdrawalPct =  Convert.ToDecimal(r["field_3"]),
    percentile = Convert.ToDecimal(r["field_4"]),
    age = Convert.ToDecimal(r["field_5"])
});
```

Now you can access this lookup in the loop very efficiently.

```
foreach (var record in inputDataLines)
{
    var fields = record.Split(',');
    var fund = fields[0];
    var bps = Convert.ToDecimal(fields[1]);
    var withdrawalPct = Convert.ToDecimal(fields[2]);
    var percentile = Convert.ToInt32(fields[3]);
    var age = Convert.ToInt32(fields[4]);
    var bombOutTerm = Convert.ToDecimal(fields[5]);

    var matchingRows = lookup[new {fund, bps, withdrawalPct, percentile, age}].ToList();

    entitiesFound.AddRange(matchingRows);

    if (matchingRows.Count() == 0)
    {
        rowsToAdd.Add(record);
    }
    else if (matchingRows.Count() == 1)
    {
        if (Convert.ToDecimal(matchingRows.First()["field_6"]) != bombOutTerm)
        {
            rowsToUpdate.Add(record);
            entitiesToUpdate.Add(matchingRows.First());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        entitiesToDelete.AddRange(matchingRows);
        rowsToAdd.Add(record);
    }
}
```

Note that this will work even if the key does not exist(an empty list is returned).

Comment: Nitpick, but won't compile because anonymous type in `lookup` is not the same you pass to its indexer.

Comment: Using the lookup type as shown drastically decreased processing time. The posted code was taking about 25 minutes. With the look up it has reduced to 20 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Add a `ToList` after your `Convert.ToDecimal(r["field_5"]) == age);`-line to force an immediate execution of the query.

```
var matchingRows = existingRecords.Entities.Where(r => r["field_1"].ToString() == fund
                                  && Convert.ToDecimal(r["field_2"]) == bps
                                  && Convert.ToDecimal(r["field_3"]) == withdrawalPct
                                  && Convert.ToDecimal(r["field_4"]) == percentile
                                  && Convert.ToDecimal(r["field_5"]) == age)
                    .ToList();
```

The `Where` doesn´t actually *execute* your query, it just *prepares* it. The actual execution happens later in a delayed way. In your case that happens when calling `Count` which itself will iterate the entire collection of items. But if the first condition fails, the second one is checked leading to a second iteration of the complete collection when calling `Count`. In this case you actually execute that query a *thrird* time when calling `matchingRows.First()`.

When forcing an *immediate execution* you´re executing the query only once and thus iterating the entire collection only once also which will decrease your overall-time.

Comment: Yes, this will reduce executing it from originally 6 times to once per input line. Still the algorithm is O(N * M), i.e. slow.

Comment: I did not know this... I've added this and it has drastically increased the performance from the previous 25 minutes to 9 minutes currently. Is this the best performance I can expect to achieve with this algorithm?

Comment: @Ben it _may_ be faster to fetch all rows from database into memory once and perform search there (in memory, via Dictionary or similar).

Comment: @Ben: look at the documentation of the LINQ methods in MSDN. There you find the term _deferred_ in every method that does not execute but build a query. Those methods can be chained without executing every single method immediately, but they have a "drawback". If you forget to execute them you will always execute them whenever you _use_ them (with methods that are not using deferred execution like `Count`, `Any`, `ToList` or a simple `foreach`-loop). That happens here.

Comment: @Ben: OP has mentioned that all records are already in memory. But that doesn't change anything because he is executing the (in-memory) query up to 5 times in every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @TimSchmelter then putting all stuff into Dictionary (keyed by string `r["field_1"].ToString() + r["field_2"]` etc) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, which is basically along the same lines as the other answers, is to prepare your data first, so that you're not repeatedly calling things like `r["field_2"]` (which are relatively slow to look up).

This is a (1) clean your data, (2) query/join your data, (3) process your data approach.

Do this:

(1)

```
var inputs =
    inputDataLines
        .Select(record =>
        {
            var fields = record.Split(',');
            return new
            {
                fund = fields[0],
                bps = Convert.ToDecimal(fields[1]),
                withdrawalPct = Convert.ToDecimal(fields[2]),
                percentile = Convert.ToInt32(fields[3]),
                age = Convert.ToInt32(fields[4]),
                bombOutTerm = Convert.ToDecimal(fields[5]),
                record
            };
        })
        .ToArray();

var entities =
    existingRecords
        .Entities
        .Select(entity => new
        {
            fund = entity["field_1"].ToString(),
            bps = Convert.ToDecimal(entity["field_2"]),
            withdrawalPct = Convert.ToDecimal(entity["field_3"]),
            percentile = Convert.ToInt32(entity["field_4"]),
            age = Convert.ToInt32(entity["field_5"]),
            bombOutTerm = Convert.ToDecimal(entity["field_6"]),
            entity
        })
        .ToArray()
        .GroupBy(x => new
        {
            x.fund,
            x.bps,
            x.withdrawalPct,
            x.percentile,
            x.age
        }, x => new
        {
            x.bombOutTerm,
            x.entity,
        });
```

(2)

```
var query =
    from i in inputs
    join e in entities on new { i.fund, i.bps, i.withdrawalPct, i.percentile, i.age } equals e.Key
    select new { input = i, matchingRows = e };
```

(3)

```
foreach (var x in query)
{
    entitiesFound.AddRange(x.matchingRows.Select(y => y.entity));

    if (x.matchingRows.Count() == 0)
    {
        rowsToAdd.Add(x.input.record);
    }
    else if (x.matchingRows.Count() == 1)
    {
        if (x.matchingRows.First().bombOutTerm != x.input.bombOutTerm)
        {
            rowsToUpdate.Add(x.input.record);
            entitiesToUpdate.Add(x.matchingRows.First().entity);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        entitiesToDelete.AddRange(x.matchingRows.Select(y => y.entity));
        rowsToAdd.Add(x.input.record);
    }
}
```

I would suspect that this will be the among the fastest approaches presented.